# x:Array в XAML от статических членов класса

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть класс

```
enum MyEnum{
  public class MyClass { 
    public static Elem1 = new A();
    public static Elem2 = new A();
    public static Elem3 = new A();
    public static Elem4 = new A();
    public static Elem5 = new A();
  }
}
```

есть XAML, но вот вопрос, как засунуть туда статические элементы? данный код не работает

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.Items>
    <x:Array xmlns:MyEnum="clr-namespace:MyEnum" Type="MyEnum:MyClass">
      <MyEnum:MyClass.Elem1/>
      <MyEnum:MyClass.Elem2/>
      <MyEnum:MyClass.Elem5/>
    </x:Array>
  </ListView.Items>
</listView>
```

Comment: `<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" .../>` не пробовали ?

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало `<x:Static Member="MyEnum:MyClass.Elem1"/>`, оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<object property="{x:Static prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}" .../>`

см. комментарий